# Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a server application that's using MySQL INNODB databases to store its data. I know that this application has worked as is in the past, but I don't know anything about the database server configuration it was using. Now while interacting with said server application using its respective client application I get the following MySQL error:

```
Aborted connection XX to db: '...' user: '...' host: '...' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

The server application meanwhile has this to say:

```
[ERROR] Database Execution Error - query '{ call sp_x8(?,?,?) }, message '[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.19]Lost connection to MySQL server during query'
[ERROR] 08S01 : try to reconnect : 08S01
[ERROR] Database Execution Error - can't execute stored procedure '{ call sp_x8(?,?,?) }'
[ERROR] Database Error - query '{ call sp_x8(?,?,?) }', param : 1(int64), 0(int), -1(int),
[ERROR] Database Execution Error - query 'rollback', message '[MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.19]MySQL server has gone away'
[ERROR] 08S01 : try to reconnect : 08S01
[ERROR] Database Execution Error - can't execute stored procedure 'rollback'
[INFO] UnhandledException
```

This happens at the same spot every time. It runs other stored procedures before just fine, but the one where the error happens is part of a larger transaction that runs several stored procedures. From the general log file:

```
23 Query    set autocommit = off
23 Prepare  call sp_x1(?,?,?)
23 Execute  call sp_x1('1','1','0')
23 Close stmt   
23 Query    commit
23 Query    set autocommit = on
46 Query    set autocommit = off
46 Prepare  call sp_x2(?,?)
46 Execute  call sp_x2('1','')
46 Close stmt   
46 Prepare  call sp_x3(?)
46 Execute  call sp_x3('1')
46 Close stmt   
46 Query    set autocommit = off
46 Prepare  call sp_x4(?,?,?)
46 Execute  call sp_x4('1','10','0')
46 Close stmt   
46 Query    commit
46 Query    set autocommit = on
46 Query    commit
46 Query    set autocommit = on
45 Query    set @@sql_select_limit=DEFAULT
45 Query    set autocommit = off
45 Prepare  call sp_x5(?,?)
45 Execute  call sp_x5('1','1024')
45 Close stmt   
45 Prepare  call sp_x6(?,?,?)
45 Execute  call sp_x6('1','1','-1')
45 Close stmt   
45 Prepare  call sp_x7(?,?,?)
45 Execute  call sp_x7('1','1','0')
45 Close stmt   
45 Prepare  call sp_x8(?,?,?)
```

This is the entire log for this session, since after that last prepare the connection is lost. I doesn't matter if I make it not run *that* SP either, it will fail on the next one coming after it then.

First I tried running the applications with the latest MySQL servers and ODBC connectors, but that actually resulted in this and other errors happening even earlier. Since the application was developed around 2014~2015 I downgraded to ODBC 5.3.4 and MySQL server 5.6.19, which got me this far.

Now the internet is full of tips about how to solve this error message, but the usual solutions are tweaking the various `timeout` and `max_allowed_packet` settings. However, changing these settings made no difference to me, the error kept happening in the same spot. Right now these settings are as follows. I know that they're ridiculous high, but I was just hoping for *some* kind of change that never came as I raised them further and further.

```
max_allowed_packet         = 1024M
interactive_timeout        = 600000
wait_timeout               = 600000
connect_timeout            = 600000
net_read_timeout           = 600000
net_write_timeout          = 600000
innodb_buffer_pool_size    = 2G
innodb_log_buffer_size     = 64M
innodb_log_file_size       = 1024M
innodb_log_files_in_group  = 3
```

I should also mention that all this happens in the span of seconds, so even default timeouts of 30 seconds shouldn't cause these errors I believe, because that entire general log snippet above takes place over the span of maybe 5 seconds.

I'm at my wits' end and I'm hoping someone might have an idea what else could be causing this error, or which versions the application might've targeted.

Comment: What values are being substituted for `?,?,?` ?

Comment: @RickJames It's a BIGINT and an INT as IN, and an INT as OUT. You can also see it in the server's error message.

Comment: How long does it take from the `BEGIN` until the error?